# Why is this search not working?

Tags: python, search, beautifulsoup, find

My goal here is for this Python script to open a block number page on blockchain.info, and take the correct table. This table is then searched for a range of values and results printed.

This one works on https://blockchain.info/search?search=422407, finding the associated "0.02269362":

```
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

#create a list of numbers that will be used in search 
list = np.arange(0.9749999312,0.9793780897,0.000001)

#open webpage, get table 
web = urllib2.urlopen("https://blockchain.info/search?search=422407").read()                   
#whole page 
soup = BeautifulSoup(web, "lxml")
table = soup.findAll("table", {'class':'table table-striped'}) #Correct table 

#Go through all numbers created; check if found; print found 
for i in list: 
    j = str(round((i * 0.023223),8))
    for line in table: #if you see a line in the table
        if line.get_text().find(j) > -1 : #and you find the specific string
        print(line.prettify().encode("utf-8")) #print it
        print j
```

I'm having difficulties doing this for others. This is supposed to go to block 422245 and find "0.02972821". It does not print off anything. Ideally it would be printing anything that matches [x.xxxx]yz and so on.

```
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

#create a list of numbers that will be used in search 
list = np.arange(0.9749999312,0.9793780897,0.000001)

#open webpage, get table 
web = urllib2.urlopen("https://blockchain.info/search?search=422245").read()  #whole page 
soup = BeautifulSoup(web, "lxml")
table = soup.findAll("table", {'class':'table table-striped'}) #Correct table 

#Go through all numbers created; check if found; print found 
for i in list: 
j = str(round((i * 0.03044589),8))
for line in table: #if you see a line in the table
    if line.get_text().find(j) > -1 : #and you find the specific string
        print(line.prettify().encode("utf-8")) #print it
        print j
```

When I tried testing the finding part of the script using the code below it also does not work. But if you go to https://blockchain.info/search?search=422245 and search on page "0.02972821" the value is there. I am confused at why this is not working.

```
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

#create a list of numbers that will be used in search 
list = np.arange(0.9749999312,0.9793780897,0.000001)

#open webpage, get table 
web = urllib2.urlopen("https://blockchain.info/search?search=422245").read()  #whole page 
soup = BeautifulSoup(web, "lxml")
table = soup.findAll("table", {'class':'table table-striped'}) #Correct table 

#Go through all numbers created; check if found; print found 
j = "0.02972821"
for line in table: #if you see a line in the table
if line.get_text().find(j) > -1 : #and you find the specific string
    print(line.prettify().encode("utf-8")) #print it
    print j
```

Comment: Have you tried doing some basic debugging on the script?  i.e. printing the contents of `table` to see if it looks right, printing each `line` as you loop, etc?  If that would produce too much output to handle, you could save the html content as a local file and edit it to remove all the extraneous information, leaving only the rows you care about.

Comment: @JohnGordon I think the problem is the 'soup = BeautifulSoup(web, "lxml")' line. Web is the whole page, but soup is a limited version of that page, therefore limiting the number of tables found.

Comment: I changed the 'lxml' to 'html.parser' and now selecting all of the correct data.